# Finding text in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Sub tupdate()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdRng As Word.Range

Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\dineshkumar.s\Documents\UiPath\PMS_Project\Template\Band 3\PMS_2019_Increment & Promotion Letter - Band 3 - Copy.docx")
For Each wdRng In wdDoc.StoryRanges

With wdRng.Find
.Text = "Emp Code"
.Replacement.Text = "0001"
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdRng = Nothing

Next wdRng
End Sub
```

When I am Running this macro it's giving user-defined type not defined

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a Reference to Word via Tools|References?

Just as importantly, this line:

```
Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdRng = Nothing
```

should *not* be inside your For/Next loop.

Your code also never saves the updated document...